# How to translate the content of a PDF file and then replace it with the translated content?

Tags: php, pdf, docx, google-translate, phpword

I know how to use the Google Translate API. I want to know one thing do you have an idea to translate the PDF file without losing in the file format. I had tried to convert the PDF file to DOCX and then translate the file and then return it to PDF but the conversion from PDF to DOCX failed because of many PHPWORD BUGs.

Here is the question and the codes that I had received in order to request the conversion from PDF to DOCX.

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Create a new PDF reader
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createReader('PDF');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

// Load the PDF file
$phpWord = $reader->load('example.pdf');

// Save the DOCX file
$writer = $PhpOfficePhpWordIOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$writer->save('example.docx');

echo 'PDF file converted to DOCX successfully!';
```

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory as WordIOFactory;

// Convert PDF to text
exec('pdftotext -layout input.pdf output.txt');

// Load text file
$text = file_get_contents('output.txt');

// Create new DOCX file
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$textrun = $section->addTextRun();
$textrun->addText($text);

// Save DOCX file
$objWriter = WordIOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('output.docx');
```

Do you have any idea how I can translate the PDF file without going through the conversion to other formats?

Comment: Within the last two years I tried adding the google translate widget some web page documents. I got it to work, only to find that the translations it produced were regularly incomprehensible. Thus, my advice to you would be to abandon this.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Can you give me an idea how to turn a PDF file into DOCX with phpword at least?

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I developed a document translation website https://officetranslator.com/, and the way of translation is same as the problem mentioned, just using different languages(**node.js**).

The translation process is not complicated:

1. Extract the text from the PDF document and obtain its position, font, size, color, and other attribute information.(**use pdf.js**)
2. Determine which words should be grouped together based on their attribute.
3. Translate the grouped text.(**use ChatGPT**)
4. Output the translated text to the original location of the text.(**use pdf-lib**)

But **the quality of the translation** depends on **how well you can perform the second step**. You may need to:

- Determine whether to merge into the same line based on the spacing between left and right positions and the font size.
- Determine whether to merge into multiple lines based on the spacing between top and bottom positions.
- Avoid illegal segmentation based on background lines (tables).
- Dynamically process the length based on whether the text is a table of contents.
- Determine whether it is a mathematical formula based on feedback from ChatGPT.
- ... Other judgments ...

This part of the processing is complex, and it may require a longer debugging time to handle it well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Google too have no idea how to handle that aspect.

They say "Do not judge a book by its cover" and from front cover to back cover google lost some of the plot.

However the core feature irrespective of contents is that that page shape drifted !! and none of the source fonts were used, all were replaced by simpler Type 1 fonts.

[image]